# Display/load a series of image using for loop

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a set of images that I want to add to my scrollview using a **for loop**. My image set is named as Route01.png , Route02.png ... in this sequence. How can I code my for loop so I can load those images in sequence. My question is mostly on how can I code **line 2** `display.newImage()`, I know I'm not doing it right. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
for i=1, 50 do
  image[i] = display.newImage("images/route/Route[i].png")
  image[i].x = display.contentCenterX
  image[i].y = spacing
  scrollView:insert(image[i])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution. I have changed line 2 to below and now all my images load to scrollview.

```
for i=1, 58 do
  image[i] = display.newImageRect( "images/route/Route" .. i .. ".jpg", 200, 60 )
  image[i].x = 90
  image[i].y = spacing
  scrollView:insert(image[i])
end
```